# Possible to split payment or add money to Microsoft Account?

Tags: store, microsoft-account

I'm trying to buy an app that's $12.99, but only have about $4 in my Microsoft Account.

When I try to buy using the account, it says my balance is too low and the transaction ends there.

[image: Can't Buy Item]

Is there a way to add more money to it, or to split the payment with credit card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't split the payment but sure you can add a credit card as a payment option. You need to go to your wallet app.

Comment: I got the Microsoft Account money from Bing Rewards (see [here](http://www.bing.com/rewards/redeem/000100000024) and [here](http://www.bing.com/rewards/redeem/000100000023)). There was already a credit card, as well as my phone account in the wallet.

Comment: So you can switch the payment option to credit card, right?

Comment: @VictorCanova That's right.