# How do I add money to my Microsoft Account?

Tags: store, microsoft-account

Sometimes it's nice to have some prepaid amount of money on the Microsoft Account so you don't have to have a credit card or a paypal account connected to it or you can give your kids an "allowance" which they can spend.

What ways are there to add some credit to my Microsoft account. Can I directly deposit some money using PayPal?

Comment: You can buy a Windows Store gift card

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/1514/106